# AngularJS как вставить своё условие валидности?

Tags: angularjs

Сделал форму для смены пароля, в ней есть два поля пароля. Хотел бы проверять их валидность и соответствие друг другу. Сделал так:

```
<p>
    <input class="form-control"  name="password" ng-model="pass1" placeholder="Пароль администратора" required type="password" >
</p>
<p>
    <input class="form-control" name="retype" ng-model="pass2" placeholder="Повторите пароль" required type="password"  >
</p>
<div class="bg-danger msg" ng-show="pass1 != pass2">Пароли не совпадают</div>
```

Но такая проблема вылезла, у меня поля ng-valid, и ng-invalid подчеркиваются красным цветом. Соответственно если пароли не совпадают хотелось бы еще чтобы второе поле красным горело а не зеленым.

Пример того как сейчас

```css
.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
  border-color: #fa787e;
}
.ng-valid.ng-dirty {
  border-color: #3c763d;
  ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" data-semver="3.3.6" data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="">
  <p>
    <input type="password" required="" placeholder="Пароль администратора" ng-model="pass1" name="password" class="form-control" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="password" required="" placeholder="Повторите пароль" ng-model="pass2" name="retype" class="form-control" />
  </p>
  <div ng-show="pass1 != pass2" class="bg-danger msg">Пароли не совпадают</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения: написать свою директиву, которая будет определять допустимое сейчас значение у модели или нет.

Для этого она должна требовать, чтобы ее использовали с директивой ngModel, То есть в описании необходимо установить

```
require: 'ngModel'
```

При такой записи, четвертым параметром в функции `link` приходит [контроллер директивы ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Далее в функции `link`, которая выполняется при связывании директивы с конкретным DOM элементом, необходимо добавить [валидатор](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators) в список валидаторов, контроллера модели

```
ctrl.$validators.sameAs = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
    return scope.$eval(attrs.sameAs) == viewValue;
};
```

В самом валидаторе просто проверяем, что значение для сравнения, такое же какое ввел пользователь.

Осталось добавить реакцию на изменения основного поля, для этого можно добавить `$watch`, в котором вызвать `$validate()` у контроллера модели, чтобы запустить проверку.

```
scope.$watch(attrs.sameAs, function() {
    ctrl.$validate();
});
```

Пример в сборе:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('sameAs', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.sameAs, function() {
          ctrl.$validate();
        });
        ctrl.$validators.sameAs = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
          return scope.$eval(attrs.sameAs) == viewValue;
        };
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
  border-color: #fa787e;
}
.ng-valid.ng-dirty {
  border-color: #3c763d;
  ;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" data-semver="3.3.6" data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>

<form name="form" ng-app="app">
  <p>
    <input type="password" required="" placeholder="Пароль администратора" ng-model="pass1" name="password" class="form-control" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="password" required="" placeholder="Повторите пароль" ng-model="pass2" name="retype" same-as="pass1" class="form-control" />
  </p>
  <div ng-show="pass1 != pass2" class="bg-danger msg">Пароли не совпадают</div>
  <pre class="bg-danger msg">errors: {{form.retype.$error|json}}</pre>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Либо есть вариант проще, либо я что-то не так понял.

```
$scope.exp = '\\d+'; // регулярка
```

Проверка по регулярке и проверка совпадения пароля

```
New:<input name="newpassword" type="password" ng-model="user.newpassword" ng-pattern="exp" />
Repeat:<input name="newpassword2" type="password" ng-model="user.newpassword2" ng-pattern="user.newpassword" />
```

Comment: то есть пароль может быть _только_ из цифр? :)

Comment: @Grundy, так регулярка же. Можем сделать только из букв :)

Comment: А если нужен пароль например `\s+`? :)

Comment: @Grundy, не пойму, это подвох какой-то? Регулярку же используем в первом паттерне. Регуляркой задаем какой угодно шаблон. Либо только цифры, либо только буквы, если надо, то цифры, буквы (прописные, строчные), символы и еще минимальное количество символов.

Comment: Я к тому, что если ввести в первое поле пароль `\s+` - то это значение может быть использовано как регулярное выражение, а значит под него подойдет любая строка из пробелов

Comment: @Grundy, хозяин-барин вполне может запретить вводить обратный слэш и прочие спецсимволы. [^\\\]